# How to run dojo on php pages

Tags: dojo

I have implemented some tutorials of dojo all this tutorials work on html web pages. Is there any way to implement dojo on php pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dojo is a javascript framework that can be used with any server technology. If you have some static html pages with dojo, the only thing you need to do is to rename them to .php.